# Why does this threaded code hang

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

In the below code, when I execute the `producercon` class, sometimes the execution stucks, looks like a deadlock. But if i make the `get_flag ()`  synchronized then there are no such problems.

I cannot figure out how there can be a problem. the `flag` can either true or false so only one of the `producer` or `consumer` will get into the `if` statement. After one of them enters the `if` it will enter the monitor with object `r` (both are initialized with the same object reference). The only problem which can happen that the `r` object being modified by the `increment_decrement ()` function call, and the `get_flag ()` reading the flag at the same time, but even then it will not enter the `if` in that iteration, but it will enter the `if` block on the next iteration, and even if the first thread did not leave the monitor, it will wait there for it (before the `synchronized` block).

How, and why is the program halting/hanging if `get_flag ()` is not made `synchronized` ?

```
import java.io.*;

class resource
{
   private boolean res, flag;

   resource ()
   {
     flag=false;
   }

   boolean get_flag ()
   {
     return flag;
   }

   void increment_decrement (String s,boolean t)
   {
     res=t;
     flag=t;
      try 
      {
        System.out.print("\n"+s+":"+res);
        Thread.sleep(200);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e)
      {
      }
   }
}

class producer implements Runnable
{
    resource r1;
    Thread t1;

    producer(resource r)
    {
      r1 = r;
      t1 = new Thread(this);
      t1.start();
    }

    public void run ()
    {  
      while (true)
      {
        if(r1.get_flag () == false)
        {
          synchronized(r1)
          {
            r1.increment_decrement("Producer",true);
          }
        }
      }
    }

   public void waitForThread () throws InterruptedException
   {
     t1.join ();
   }
}

class consumer implements Runnable
{
   resource r2;
   Thread t2;

   consumer(resource r)
   {
     r2 = r;
     t2 = new Thread (this);
     t2.start();
   }

   public void run()
   {
     while (true)
     {
       if(r2.get_flag () == true)
       {
         synchronized(r2)
         {
           r2.increment_decrement("Consumer",false);
         }
       }
     }
   }

   public void waitForThread () throws InterruptedException
   {
     t2.join ();
   }
} 

public class producercon
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     try
     {
        System.out.print("PRESS CTRL+C TO TERMINATE\n");

        resource r = new resource();
        consumer c = new consumer(r);
        producer p = new producer(r);

        c.waitForThread ();
        p.waitForThread ();
     }
     catch(InterruptedException e)
     {
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, you really should name your classes with a uppercased first letter : Producer, Consumer, Resource...

Comment: @OlivierCroisier: agreed, (a code of a friend of mine, posted the original)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your call to get_flag() is not thread safe nor volatile.  This means in the cache of thread 1 it can be true while in the cache of thread 2 it can be false.

Comment: but why does making `get_flag ()` synchronized work ? does making it synchronized enforce the flag to be read from the memory?

Comment: Yes. so does making it `volatile`. Otherwise the value can be cached locally or even placed in a register and not read from memory. You can write this code without synchronized at all. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your boolean either `volatile` or an `AtomicBoolean`.  Right now multiple threads are trying to access the boolean that is in no way synchronized.

Comment: but why does making `get_flag ()` synchronized work ? does making it synchronized enforce the flag to be read from the memory?

Comment: It forces an update or access to be synchronized between threads.  With `volatile` this is accomplished with the memory barrier which ensures that all updates by other threads are completed before the value is read on the current thread.  `AtomicBoolean` also guarantees that the updates are synchronized between threads.

Answer (score 0):

This producer/consumer implementation is quite weird.

Neither the producer not the consumer wait for the resource to be in the adequate state, and the resource access is not well protected (the flag should be guarded by some lock to ensure its visibility between threads).

One way to improve on this design would be to use the standart wait/notify system. Another way would be to use a Semaphore in the Resource to ensure only one thread can access the resource at one given time. Finally, you could use a higher-level construct such an java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue to pass some data directly from the producer to the consumer.

Comment: yes, that is correct, but the main goal was to know why was the program halting.